# Am I mining at DwarfPool right?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

I am using Geth and ethminer to mine at DwarfPool. I used the command `geth -rpc` to run geth, then I open another cmd and run the command `ethminer --opencl-device 0 -G -F https://eth-eu.dwarfpool.com:80/0x1c14b774cf7aae21eb4f06bebe98dd9b05c128ba` do I need geth open? The wallet address I'm using is not from geth but from Jaxx.

These are the links where I got my stuff:

Geth: https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/

Ethmiiner: https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/releases

When I run the command it tells me I'm mining 0.00MH/S

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mining is not enabled anymore on the mainnet, the geth client removed the mining support, and DwarfPool is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be running geth to run ethminer in pool mode, only for solo mode.